# Flutter data serialization and deserialization with firestore db

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I ran into this weird error in Flutter. I'm using a custom data model:

```
class ScanData {
  final String userID;
  final String companyID;
  final String scanID;
  final String deviceID;
  final String model;
  final Map result;
  final DateTime dateTime;
  final GeoPoint geoPoint;

  ScanData(
      {this.userID,
      this.companyID,
      this.scanID,
      this.deviceID,
      this.model,
      this.result,
      this.geoPoint,
      this.dateTime});

  factory ScanData.fromMap(Map data) {
    return ScanData(
      userID: data['userID'] ?? '',
      companyID: data['companyID'] ?? '',
      scanID: data['scanID'] ?? '',
      deviceID: data['deviceID'] ?? '',
      model: data['model'] ?? '',
      result: data['result'] ?? {},
      dateTime: data['dateTime'] as DateTime ?? DateTime.now(),
      geoPoint: data['geoPoint'] as GeoPoint ?? ['77', '28'],
    );
  }
}
```

Created a method in Collection class to retrieve data from firestore:

```
class Collection<T> {
  final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final String path;
  CollectionReference ref;

  Collection({this.path}) {
    ref = _db.collection(path);
  }

  Future<List<T>> getData() async {
    var snapshots = await ref.get();
    return snapshots.docs
        .map((doc) => Global.models[T](doc.data) as T)
        .toList();
  }
}
```

Calling it in widget, this works if I don't use the data model and instead call the collection directly, but it's much easier since I don't want to create it everywhere I go and helps with type checking and intellisense...

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: Collection<ScanData>(path: 'scans').getData(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ScanData>> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.hasError) {
            return Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                } else {
                return _buildScansList(snapshot.data);
                }
           },
         )
```

Globals:

```
class Global {

  static final Map models = {
    ScanData: (data) => ScanData.fromMap(data),
  };
}
```

The error (occurs in Globals fromMap):

```
Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type '() => Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>')
```

I tried putting the following in the ScanData model

```
factory ScanData.fromMap(Map<String,dynamic> data) {...}
```

but this gives another error:

```
Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type '() => Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')
```

:| Any tips appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to encode and decode from-to JSON. Some bug is there in firestore. Not sure tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method getData() of Collection class, `doc.data` is not property, it's a method, so just add `()`.

Comment: Works. Thanks a ton, m8!